# Elasticsearch lucene query with regexp

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana, filebeat

I was trying to count logs stored in Elasticsearch within Grafana.

Log Pattern:

```
Writing in bulk entries: driverMapLen= 4 , queueLen= 423
Writing in bulk entries: driverMapLen= 3 , queueLen= 345
Writing in bulk entries: driverMapLen= 5 , queueLen= 399
Writing in bulk entries: driverMapLen= 3 , queueLen= 246
```

My intention was to count logs with `queueLen` greater (>) than `300`.

With **regexp**, I can use `queueLen= [3-9][0-9]{2}` to filter as I want.

But, in Grafana, this query doesn't work.

[image]

I tried some other options. But I think I am going to wrong direction.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of ES and Grafana you are using?

Comment: ES: 6.4.0 & Grafana: latest

Comment: In our Grafana we can use regex when we enclose it in "/", e.g. `/queueLen= [3-9][0-9]{2}/` to mark it as a regex expression.